# Should questions about SE and not about PSE be moved to MSO?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

Sorry about the all the acronyms in the title.  There are many questions here on Meta Programmers that are neither:

- about Programmers.SE at all
- about a general SE problem, but related to a question on Programmers.SE

Should these questions be flagged for migration to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) (where they can often be closed as duplicates)? Examples include the following:

- [Why is it only 5 reputation points for an up vote on a question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/why-is-it-only-5-reputation-points-for-an-up-vote-on-a-question)
- [Badge progress display like the Percentage Till privilages display](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/badge-progress-display-like-the-percentage-till-privilages-display)
- [Upvote In Community Wiki](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/upvote-in-community-wiki)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no. My personal approach is to not migrate questions that have been frequently asked/answered on MSO, since they'll just add to the noise and get closed anyway. I find it more valuable to provide a good answer here in those situations.

Far as bug reports go, site-specific metas do get attention from the SE dev team, so posting them here is fine. Although, they will get attention sooner on the main site.

Comment: +1 on addition of noise on MSO.(redundancy aside)At least now you can have duplicates here to be closed here.Also a search here would probably pop up the duplicate.One might consider that the OP's might not have searched MSO as they are more active on ProgrammersSE